# Prove there exists $y\neq 0$ but $x\cdot y=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I would like to know if I'm missing something with my solution - as an earlier version was wrong and I think I've managed to patch it up - to this problem from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. Every solution I've read online always breaks it up into two cases: $k$ even and $k$ odd which makes me feel I might be wrong somewhere as I believe my solution is much simpler, if correct.

> **Problem 1.18** If $k \geq2$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$, prove that there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $y \neq 0$ but $x \cdot y =0$.

**Proof**: Assume $x \neq 0$ as otherwise any non-zero $y$ would do. If $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ is non-zero then there is a pair $x_i \text{ and } x_j$ with $1 \leq i < j \leq k$ such that at least one is not zero. Letting $y = (0_1, \ldots, 0_{i-1}, -x_j, 0_{i+1},\ldots,0_{j-1}, x_i, 0_{j+1},\dots,0_k)$ we have $x\cdot y = 0$.

Thank you.

Comment: What if $x=(1,0,0,\dotsc,0)$?

Comment: Then $y = (0,-1,0,\ldots,0)$

Comment: Why "there is a pair"?? It could be, say $\,(1,0,0...,0)\,$ ...

Comment: @BryanUrízar He is quibbling with you language, I think. "... both are not zero" means $x_i\neq 0$ and $x_j\neq 0$. You mean "at least one is non-zero."

Comment: Ah wait, yes that is what I mean. Sorry.

Comment: @BryanUrízar Yes, that is what I was getting at. The proof now looks fine. I was going to say you don't need indices on the $0$s, but I actually quite like that as a way of indicating where the non-zero entries are.

Comment: @MattPressland I had actually been confusing myself on how to say it right but I got it wrong in the end. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another inductive approach - Induction on $\,k\,$ :

$$\text{For}\;\;\,k=2:\,(0,0)\neq(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2\implies (a,b)\cdot(-b,a)=0\;\;\wedge\;\;(-b,a)\neq(0,0)$$

Assume for $\,k-1\ge1\,$ and show for $\,k\,$: let $\;(a_1,...,a_k)\neq (0,0,...,0)\,$ :

If $\,\;\exists\,1\leq j\le k-1\;\;s.t.\;\;a_j\neq0\,$ we're done (why?), otherwise it **must** be that $\,a_k\neq 0\;\wedge\;\;a_j=0\;,\;j=1,2,...,k-1\,$ . Then simply choose $\,(1,0,...,0)\,$

Question: where did the inductive hypothesis kick in the above?

Comment: I don't think I'm following your proof. If there is a $a_j \neq 0$ with $ 1 \leq j \leq k - 1$ I know by the induction hypothesis that there is a $y$ of length $k - 1$ such that $(a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1}) \cdot y = 0$ and if I let $y' = (y,0)$ it is of length $k$ and it satisfies $(a_1,\ldots,a_k) \cdot y' = 0$. I think then you mean that otherwise $a_k \neq 0$ and $a_1=\ldots=a_{k-1}=0$  . Then $y = (a_k,0,\ldots,0)$, for example, would work. I'm missing something right?

Comment: Yes, of course. The first one is a typo, the second one pure stupid mistake of mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that uses neither coordinates nor $k$ (the dimension):

Assume $x\neq 0$, otherwise any $y$ is a solution.

Because the dimension is two or higher, there must be $z$ such that $z\not\in \mbox{span}(\{x\})$. Let
$$y=z-\frac{x\cdot z}{x\cdot x}x$$

Then $y$ is non-zero (otherwise $z$ would be a multiple of $x$) and
\begin{align}
x\cdot y &= x\cdot(z-\frac{x\cdot z}{x\cdot x}x) \\
&= x\cdot z-\frac{x\cdot z}{x\cdot x}(x\cdot x) \\
&= x\cdot z-x\cdot z \\
&= 0
\end{align}

---

This proof a simple geometric interpretation: Pick any vector not parallel to $x$ and subtract just enough of $x$ so that the result is perpendicular to it. (I'd like to add an image but I don't know a proper tool to make such image fast and nice.)

Comment: This is really really nice. Thank-you!