# Checking Proof: Given $\boldsymbol{x}$ there exists a $\boldsymbol{y}$ where $\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y} = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis

Let bold type-face denote a k-tuple in $\mathbb{R}^k$

**Proposition:** Suppose there is a, $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ where $k\ge2$. Then there exists a $\boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ where $\boldsymbol{y} \ne \boldsymbol{0}$ such that $\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y} = 0 $

**Proof:** Suppose $k=2$, then $\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y} = \sum_{i=1}^2 x_iy_i=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$. Thus, by allowing $y_1=\dfrac{1}{x_1}$ and $y_2 = \dfrac{1}{-x_2}$ the expression goes to zero. Thus there is at least one $\boldsymbol{y}$ that satisfies the expression.

Suppose that the proposition is true for $k=n$, then it must also be true for $k=n+1$.

Suppose $k=n+1$, then $\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y} = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_iy_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}$. Based upon the inductive assumption, the first $n$ values of $\boldsymbol{y}$ can be set such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i=0$ where $y_i \ne 0$ for at least one $i=1,2,...,n$. Set $y_{n+1}$ to zero, thus, the whole expression is zero and there is at least one $\boldsymbol{y} \ne \boldsymbol{0}$ where $\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y} = 0$ $\square$

**Question:** I would like to request some feedback on my proof. In what ways may it be improved?

**Source:** Rudin, W (1976). *Principles of Mathematical Analysis (ed. 3).*

Comment: Why can we set $y_1 = \frac{1}{x_1}$? What if $x= (0,1)$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Good point. Guess I will have to rework that.

Comment: While that is a good point, you should look at my hint, and approach the question differently. There is a very obvious guess that works for any vector that is not the zero vector.

Comment: @JordanMahar Please clarify: your question asks for $x\cdot y \ne 0$ but your proof is clearly seeking the opposite $x\cdot y = 0$.

Comment: You have written down the problem incorrectly.  Rudin asks you to prove the existence of $y \ne 0$ such that $x \cdot y = 0$.

Comment: @ErickWong It is meant to be zero. Wrong sign put down. Thanks for asking for clarification.

Comment: I asked a similar question. I give a proof of this and two others replied with different proofs. You might find it instructive: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377290/prove-there-exists-y-neq-0-but-x-cdot-y-0

Answer (score 3):

Okay I see OP has a typo in the proposition.

By geometry, $\newcommand{\b}{\boldsymbol}\b{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ that is not zero uniquely defines a plane with codimension 1 by being its normal vector. Any nonzero vector $\b{y}$ living on this plane satisfies $\b{x}\cdot \b{y}= 0$.

For $\mathbb{R}^2$, a rotation by $\pi/2$ will do, i.e., let $\b{y} = (x_2,-x_1)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin The OP wanna show there exists $y$ such that $xy \neq 0$?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what came over me. Your's is exactly what I meant, and something tripped in my head.

Comment: @CalvinLin There is a typo in OP's proposition, my bad for not reading carefully.

Comment: Ah yes, so that was what tripped. In either case, there are lots of easy guesses for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you are missing the possibility that $x_1 = 0$, since we can't divide by 0.

**Hint:** There is a very easy vector to guess.